# Configure beans file for repositories

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have two interface with same name but in different packages.
As I `autowired` them I have to give them name.
My interfaces are `com.example.mysql.UserRepository` and `com.example.mongo.UserRepository`.

So I have declared them like this:

```
@Repository(value = "mysqlrepo")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> ...
```

and

```
@Repository(value = "mongorepo")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User,String> ...
```

and used them like this:

```
@Autowired
ee3.demo.repositories.mysql.UserRepository userRepository;

@Qualifier("mongorepo")
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository1;
```

Now I wonder how can I do this with beans configure file.
I tried `<bean id="mysqlService" lazy-init="true" class="ee3.demo.repositories.mysql.UserRepository"/>`
but I am getting error `interface not allowed for non abstract beans`.
I wondering what is the correct way of doing this,
this question if different with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923058/cannot-autowire-repository-service-spring-jpa) question as this question have just one interface and don't need to use qualifier to specify which interface he need
What I have tried so far is [HERE](https://github.com/joeprintfffffff/ee3)

Comment: I think you should use [`MongoRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html) interface instead of `JpaRepository` in the second case.

Comment: yes,Thanks, I fixed it

Comment: You say that your question is different from the linked one but you get the same error. If you try proposed solutions (remove bad `<bean>` declaration from your config) you'll resolve your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure Spring Data using XML config you don't need to declare beans for all your repositories. See [Spring Data docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories) here. It's easier to specify a base package for scanning:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

  <!-- 
    Configure Spring Data JPA / MongoDB and set the base package of the 
    repository interfaces 
  -->
  <jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.mysql"/>
  <mongo:repositories base-package="com.example.mongo"/>

 ...
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25049778/1429387) in this post.

---

**EDIT**

You need to give different names to your repositories (use `value` attribute on annotation). I suspect that if you have multiple interfaces with the same name `UserRepository`, all of them would be overridden by the latest declared bean.  This is a modified code from [GitHub](https://github.com/joeprintfffffff/ee3)

DemoApplication.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
//@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

beans.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
</beans>
```

mysql.UserRepository.java

```java
@Repository(value = "userRepositoryJpa")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    User findByName(String name);
}
```

mongodb.UserRepository.java

```java
@Repository(value = "userRepositoryMongo")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<UserMongo, String> {
    User findByName(String name);
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Another option is to write your own implementations for these interfaces and reference them from XML. You need to remove `@Repository`, `@EnableJpaRepositories`, `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotations also. You need to implement all methods by yourself. But you lose the benefits of Spring Data... Look for [Custom implementations for Spring Data repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) in docs.

```java
public interface UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
    public User findByName(String name) {
        // your custom implementation
    }
}
```

XML Configuration example

```xml
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.repositories.mysql" repository-impl-postfix="Impl" />  
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.example.repositories.mongodb" repository-impl-postfix="Impl" />  

<beans:bean id="jpaUserRepositoryImpl" class="com.example.repositories.mysql.UserRepositoryImpl">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="mongoUserRepositoryImpl" class="com.example.repositories.mongodb.UserRepositoryImpl">
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: how can I use them with `@AutoWired` and `@Qualifier` for instanciating them?

Comment: Can you `@Autowire` by type, and not by name? Then you don't need qualifier

Comment: Im getting error `Could not Autowired. There is more than one bean of UserRepository type`

Comment: @joegates Sorry for being rude, it seems like another question, and this one can be closed =)

Comment: @joegates what have you changed in your code to get this error?

Comment: I changed my configururation file as you said

Comment: @joegates Please show us the new code. Since now, when the code in question differs from your actual code, it's difficult to talk about your problem. I suggest you to edit this question or ask a different question and post your new code.

Comment: I believe that if you autowire like this `@Autowired com.example.mysql.UserRepository userRepository;` you shouldn't have any problems

Comment: and Im getting this error when change my configuration file `Field userRepository in ee3.demo.controllers.SiteController required a bean of type 'ee3.demo.repositories.mysql.UserRepository' that could not be found.
`

Comment: @joegates ok, I'll look through it

Comment: @joegates I've edited my answer. Please try this code

Comment: Thanks for you time but I have asked this question As I want to configure this with xml file not annotation

Comment: @joegates Oh, I think I've found the real problem. Two interfaces with the same name `UserRepository` interfere and when Spring Data creates two beans with name `UserRepository` one of them is overridden by the other. This results in "Bean could not be found" exception. See my answer again and try to give different names to your repositories. (NO YOU STILL DON'T NEED XML CONFIG)

Answer (score 1):

You must desclare alias for these beans

For example

```
<bean id="mysqlService" lazy-init="true" alias="mysqlrepoAlias"
 class="ee3.demo.repositories.mysql.UserRepository"/>

<bean id="mongorepoService" lazy-init="true"  alias="mongorepoAlias"class="ee3.demo.repositories.mysql.UserRepository"/>
```

Comment: are you sure I can use alias like this ? and please give some more detail about `alias` jobs

Comment: @Joe  you can look https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-beanname-alias

Comment: Well, This is not what I am looking for, my problem is not use alias for class name, my problem is `interface` that can't used in beans and I need to name this repository

Comment: I was looking for you ..I find this example .I think it will fix your issue http://www.mytechnotes.biz/2013/03/spring-jparepository-example-in-memory.html

Comment: Not really, this is not what I am looking for, I am configuring my application use xml files

Comment: @java.nazif the domain name has changed https://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2013/03/spring-jparepository-example-in-memory.html